# EJB 3 and Spring @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, transactions, ejb

For some reason one of my ejb bean indirectly calls a DAO that is annotated with springs @Transactional annotation

When I run the code with the above setup, i get a transaction exception like below

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) ~[jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) ~[jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) ~[jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) ~[jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) ~[jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar!/:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$1.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:71) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) ~[jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar!/:7.1.1.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_29]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) ~[na:na]
```

My bean definition for transaction manager looks like

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can anyone throw some light on what is the issue and how I should correct it ?

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough info. Can we see some of the code that is running? Perhaps a bit of the stack trace above the first line you provided?

Comment: You are using EJB but are trying local transactions, I would expect that you have to use JTA transactions to participate in the ongoing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark your EJB method with `@TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)`.

However, if you want to use Spring and EJB together, and even with Hibernate (JPA) you should rely just only on container services: allow to raise JPA by JBOSS, get transaction manager for Spring from JNDI (just enough to add `<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>`) and etc.

From other side, if you have Spring, why do you need EJB ?

Comment: Thanks Artem, I tried to annotate my dao classes with @TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED), it doesnt seem to resolve the issue. If I use <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>, how do I provide the datasource .sessionFactory etc.

Comment: 1. Why do you need `sessionFactory`, if you use JPA? 2. `DataSource` has to be picked up by JBOSS container too, and you can get it for Spring from JNDI.